# Why this code is valid: "(1,eval)('this')"

Tags: javascript

Why next code is valid Javascript code?

```
var global = (1,eval)('this');

alert(global);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) returns its second operand (and evaluates both).

The code in your question is equivalent to:

```
1;
var global = eval('this');
alert(global);
```

Comment: Can you explain or may be some link will be useful too, really confused.

Comment: @Sheikh, I did link to the MDN documentation in my answer :) Basically, `(1, eval)` applies the comma operator `,` to `1` and `eval`. The operator evaluates `1`, then evaluates and returns `eval`. Therefore, `foo = (1, eval)(something)` is equivalent to `1; foo = eval(something);`.